# How to compare several matrices and calculate the percentage difference in R

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose that's my data example

```
nrow<-4
ncol<-5
m1 <- matrix(rbinom(nrow*ncol,1,.5),nrow,ncol)
m2 <- matrix(rbinom(nrow*ncol,1,.5),nrow,ncol)
m3 <- matrix(rbinom(nrow*ncol,1,.5),nrow,ncol)
```

I need to compare 3 matrices sequentially. According to this principle.
Eg

m1

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1 0 1 0 1
[2,] 1 1 1 0 1
[3,] 1 0 0 1 1
[4,] 0 0 0 1 0
```

m2

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1 0 0 0 1
[2,] 0 1 1 0 0
[3,] 1 0 0 0 0
[4,] 0 1 0 1 0
```

.
Now count the number of matches in each column of the matrix. Take the first column of both matrices

```
    m1 m2

    1 1 matched values
    1 0 values did not match
    1 1 matched values
    0 0 matched values
```

in total, out of 4 values in the first columns of matrices `m1` and `m2`, 3 coincided. It turns out that 75% of the values coincided.

then take the second column

```
 m1   m2
[,2] [,2] 
0     0 matched values
1     1 matched values
0     0 values did not match
0     1 values did not match
```

here is also a similar situation where 3 values coincided

in other words, as the desired output
there must be something like

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1 0 1 0 1
[2,] 1 1 1 0 1
[3,] 1 0 0 1 1
[4,] 0 0 0 1 0


    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 1 0 0 0 1
[2,] 0 1 1 0 0
[3,] 1 0 0 0 0
[4,] 0 1 0 1 0
    75 75 75 75 50
```

Now let's calculate the average value of the percentages received. = 70%

```
(75+75+75+75+50)/5=70
```

What is the simplest way to calculate the percentage difference between all matrices?
first between `m1` and `m2`, then between `m1` and `m3`, and lastly between `m2` and `m3`

Thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks as always, for generating sample data, but please edit your question (and subsequent results) using a seed (ie, `set.seed(123)`) so that we can recreate the exact same result and all be on the same page. Good luck!

Comment: `mean(m1 == m2)` will likely give you what you want for individual comparisons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two base R options

- `combn` + `mean`

`combn` generates combination pairs, and `mean` tells the mean of co-occurrences.

```
combn(
    lst,
    2,
    \(x) mean(do.call(`==`,x))
)
```

you will obtain

```
[1] 0.5 0.4 0.5
```

- `adist` + `toString`

This approach generates a matrix that depicts the co-occurrences.

```
> 1 - adist(unlist(lapply(lst, toString))) / lengths(lst)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.5  0.4
[2,]  0.5  1.0  0.5
[3,]  0.4  0.5  1.0
```

---

## Data

```
set.seed(0)
nrow <- 4
ncol <- 5
m1 <- matrix(rbinom(nrow * ncol, 1, .5), nrow, ncol)
m2 <- matrix(rbinom(nrow * ncol, 1, .5), nrow, ncol)
m3 <- matrix(rbinom(nrow * ncol, 1, .5), nrow, ncol)

lst <- list(m1, m2, m3)
```

Comment: ,thank you for your simple and very good answer.  May i ask you help  me in this topic, it is derived from this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77292882/how-to-calculate-p-value-when-comparing-the-percentage-similarity-of-matrices-in